# Error when trying to install pyjaco

Tags: javascript, python, git, python-3.x

I'm trying to install pyjaco, on windows, from the tutorial [here](https://github.com/chrivers/pyjaco) (I am trying to do the standard install) I did: `git clone https://github.com/chrivers/pyjaco` from the cmd, and then I `cd pyjaco`. Next, I do `python setup.py install` it gives me this error: `'python' is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. So I open file explorer, and open setup.py in IDLE:

```
from distutils.core import setup
try:
        from setuptools import setup
except:
        pass

setup(
    name = "pyjaco",
    version = "1.0.0",
    author = "Pyjaco development team",
    author_email = "developer@pyjaco.org",
    description = ("Python to JavaScript translator"),
    scripts = ["pyjs.py"],
    url = "http://pyjaco.org",
    keywords = "python javascript translator compiler",
    packages=["pyjaco", "pyjaco.compiler"],
    package_data={"pyjaco": ["stdlib/*.js"]}
)
```

I get this error when I run it, in the python shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iFunny\pyjaco\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    package_data={"pyjaco": ["stdlib/*.js"]}
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    raise SystemExit(gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg)
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...
]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I believe it is the distutils.core import error because of: `\python32\lib\distutils\core.py`

I did a little bit of googleing and found that I need to run ez_setup.py( you can find it [here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py)). 
So I ran that, and in C:\Program Files (x86)\python32\Lib\site-packages it installed:

setuptools-2.2-py3.2.egg, setuptools.pth, and easy-install.pth. How can I get this to install properly?

Comment: Just run pip to install pyjaco .

Comment: in cmd.. same thing: pip is not recongized

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way to install any python module is to use the pip or easy_install . `pip install pyjaco` .

So , first you need to install pip . To install pip, run the python script available here:  [get-pip.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py)

I also tried to install it by downloading the tar file and run the setup.py, it worked perfectly.

[image]